# HERE-API recognize the floor/ground plane of the building

Tags: google-maps, maps, here-api

Is there a way in HERE-API to recognize the floor/ground plane of the building on a map? I can't find it anymore, but google have a code-snippet of doing just that.

Is HERE-API having such feature?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you provide some example code you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Android / iOS premium SDKs with Venue maps? You can get and extract the ground floor foot print and find out if you are inside of a building.

The SDK documentation is [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/topics/venue-faq.html). You can start from the [getVenue](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-venues3d-venueservice.html#topic-apiref__getvenueat-geocoordinate-float) API to download the venue information. And from the [Venue](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-venues3d-venue.html) class, you can find out the layout of each floor including each space in the floor.

There is even a [tutorial](https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/tree/master/3d-venues-and-indoor-routing) as a bonus.